# Job not inserting in job table - lumen queue

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen, supervisord

there is 2 projects - project1, project2 (both project connected with same database)

in project1, implemented queue which is inserting data into jobs table

in project2, implemented queue which is not inserting data into jobs table.

please help me here

controller:

```
public function update_queue(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    dispatch(new StoreElasticListToReddis($input));
    return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

Comment: Can please share your both code to insert data from both projects?

Comment: I have added code to my question. this code is similar for both projects. please see

Comment: Try to run this commands: 
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart